# How do I decode UTF-8 string in \x format to Unicode?

Tags: php, unicode, encoding

I have the Unicode string in this format:

```
$str = '\x576879204920616d';
```

I know that it resolves to the following words in Unicode:

```
Why I am
```

But I don't know how to do it in PHP.

Incidentally, I know it can be done. I've used one of the online sites and it's possible:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Trim off the nonsense and convert from hex.

```
$in = '\x576879204920616d';
$out = hex2bin(substr($in,2));

var_dump($out); // string(8) "Why I am"
```

I don't know what you have producing that output format, but it's just generic hex-encoding and has nothing to do with UTF8 or Unicode.

Comment: It's coming from the Python script that is saving strings in various encodings to DB by first encoding them : str.encode('UTF-8', 'surrogatepass')

Comment: @jjj This smells like Postgres encoding problem. I've seen postgres _display_ perfectly valid data like this because of an incorrectly specified encoding.

Answer (score 1):

use of the direct mapping between UTF-16BE (big endian) and the Unicode codepoint

```
   $str = '\x576879204920616d'; 
   echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
```